# Using PostgreSQL at web host, editing pg_hba.conf

Tags: php, postgresql, web-hosting

I have a domain at HelioHost.org, where I want to connect to a PostgreSQL server, which they supposedly support. But I get the following error message when looking at my PHP files in Firefox:

```
Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "64.62.211.132", user "username", database "database_name", SSL off in /pathway/php_file.php on line 555
```

I am new to working with servers and web hosting. Do I have to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file on their server to get this to work, and is there in that case a way to do this? You can use phpPgAdmin from HelioHost.org, but I can't find a way to edit this file from there.

Comment: The message tipically means pg_hba.conf cannot find a rule for the ip in your connection string, but from the message you're passing 'ip.address' as the ip. Check your php configuration and see if the postgres connection string is right.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wrote "ip.address" as in my actual IP-address. Not very clear perhaps..

Comment: I wasn't able to see the docs for HeliosHost but the error means pg_hba.conf is configured in a way that blocks access to the user you're using. If the hosting service does not give you access to such configuration they must provide the user which can access the database. You can fi d more about the actual file format in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Thanks! I have asked HelioHost about this, but without an answer. Am now trying another hosting alternative.